# Copy Table also match id

Tags: c#, mysql

Table Name 04.04.2016

```
===========================                      
id       3                         
name     asd                    
co       12                         
price    32                         
st       4
```

Table Name 05.04.2016

```
=======================
id     3         Same
name   asd      Same
co <--- FROM  old one  ST= HERE
------------------
price 32        Same`enter code here`
st      Null  <--- I will write here later
```

Table-04.04.2016  is old one

I want to open New Table also old table 'ST' column copy to new table 'CO' At all

but I need to match id as well

```
private void Bsayim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + tarihbugun.Text + "` (" +
      "`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT," +
      "`urun` VARCHAR(255)," +
      "`gelen` VARCHAR(255)," +
      "`fiyat` VARCHAR(255)," +
      "`kalan` VARCHAR(255), " +
      "`giden` VARCHAR(255), " +
      "`maliyet` VARCHAR(255), " +
      "PRIMARY KEY(id));", conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmdDatabase.Dispose();
        conn.Close();


        datagird();


        if (MessageBox.Show("message", "new day", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new MySqlCommand();

            try
            {
                sqlCmd1.Connection = conn;
                sqlCmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `" + date.Text + "`(`id`,`product`, `pprice`) SELECT `aid`, `aproduct`, `aprice` FROM Alcol";


                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd1);

                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

                bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                sda.Update(dbdataset);

                MessageBox.Show("ok","ok",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

I Open the table 05.04.2016 with these code. Now how to copy 'ST' from old table to new tables 'CO'

Comment: private void Bsayim_Click is working there are alot of diffrent name but doesnt matter :)   Just how to move  I need to know Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it  I hope that This code will help someone.

```
 string Query = "UPDATE  `11.04.2016` AS t1 INNER JOIN  `10.04.2016` AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id SET t1.xx = t2.yy";
        //This is  MySqlConnection here i have created the object and pass my connection string.  
        //   MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
        conn.Open();
        MyReader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
        while (MyReader2.Read())
```

UPDATE  `Table_name` AS t1 INNER JOIN  `Old_table` AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id SET t1.Columnname = t2.othercolumnname